# Clipping images in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, clip

So I created square buffer points on a satellite image and I am trying to cut the images under these buffer points as like a JPEG or PNG file. Is there any way to do this in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

If your "square buffer points" aren't polygons, make them into polygons.

If your "square buffer points" are polygons, use the `Clip raster by mask layer` tool (Raster menu > Extraction).

Comment: How do I make "square buffer points" into polygons? I'm still very new to QGIS

Comment: I can't answer that because I don't know what you mean by "square buffer points." If you can explain what they are, I can explain how to make them into polygons.